# mysql:Update with Join

Tags: mysql

```
company contains id,company_name

company_alias contains id,company_id,company_alias

company_rawdata contains id,complaint descrption,company_match
```

I am trying to update company_match with company_name where company descrption contains alias name.

```
 update company_rawdata cr inner join company c on c.company_name 
 like concat('',cr.complaint_descrption,'') set cr.matched_company = c.company_name
```

Comment: post your code and we will guide you.

Comment: update company_rawdata cr
inner join company c
on c.company_name like concat('',cr.complaint_against,'')
set cr.matched_company = c.company_name

Comment: not able to join all 3 tables..

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE company_rawdata r
INNER JOIN company_alias a ON a.company_alias = r.description
INNER JOIN company c ON c.id = a.company_id
SET r.company_match = c.company_name
```

Or, the following if `a.company_alias` is contained somewhere within `a.company_alias`:

```
UPDATE company_rawdata r
INNER JOIN company_alias a ON a.company_alias LIKE CONCAT('%', r.description, '%')
INNER JOIN company c ON c.id = a.company_id
SET r.company_match = c.company_name
```

Comment: a.company_alias = r.description not equal..for example description contains 'vodaphone online complaints' and company_alias contains vadaphone,vadafone

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
 UPDATE company c
 INNER JOIN company_alias a ON a.company_id = c.id
 INNER JOIN company_rawdata r ON a.company_alias = r.company_match
 SET r.company_match = c.company_name
```

Comment: you should say what the relations between tables , we are not going to guess them.

Comment: it appears to me that the OP is looking to update `company_rawdata` and not `company`.